# does pg_dumpall run vacuum?

Tags: postgresql, dump, size

Can someone confirm if `pg_dumpall` does a vacuum? I cannot explain the size differences between a local and dumped database but thinking duplicate/rewritten entries are ignored

1. 350mb inside `psql` with `\l`
2. 350mb with `du -sch` at postgres' folder
3. 158mb with `pgdumpall` to file

running pgsql 9.5

Answer (score 4):

The size reported by `psql -l` includes the size of all indexes.

The dump only contains the *definition* of the indexes, but no data for them, that's why the dump file is (substantially) smaller then the reported size on disk.

In addition to the size of the indexes, the dump only contains the raw data, while the size on disk might include table bloat (free space inside the table's data files)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

dump_all takes the *current* records in each table and writes them to a file.
Any "old" or inaccessible rows, that are eligible for vacuuming, are not written, so the dump file will be smaller.

As a_horse_with_no_name says, only Index *definitions* are written to the file, saving yet more space.
The indexes are reconstructed from scratch when the dump is loaded into a new database.

Comment: Thanks both. That answer my question